# apache poi library error 2

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm trying to include the apache poi library with Maven. All is fine except when I try to compile it I get the following error. How would I reduce the method references? I only need to read and write .xlsx files. Has anyone successfully utilised apache poi in an android app without getting this error?

Cheers

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\tsuyoshiq\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio2\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\tsuyoshiq\Desktop\Prensa\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-beta2-74bd62d2e75e960b3f516758040beb598c0c3c0a.jar C:\Users\tsuyoshiq\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.11-beta2\76e88385937608ef805a040b35185220e5d95ea1\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-beta2.jar
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    trouble writing output: Too many method references: 73431; max is 65536.
    You may try using --multi-dex option.
    References by package:
       460 com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.encryption
       136 com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.encryption.impl
        35 com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.keyEncryptor.certificate
        17 com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.keyEncryptor.certificate.impl
        71 com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.keyEncryptor.password
        53 com.microsoft.schemas.office.x2006.keyEncryptor.password.impl
        13 java.lang
         1 java.lang.reflect
         5 java.util
         1 javax.xml.namespace
        66 org.apache.xmlbeans
        19 org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values
         1 org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.xb.xmlschema
      2971 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart
      1738 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.impl
      8827 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main
      5294 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.impl
        86 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture
        33 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.picture.impl
       745 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing
       417 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.impl
       230 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing
       164 org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.wordprocessingDrawing.impl
       298 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties
       256 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.customProperties.impl
       617 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes
       596 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.docPropsVTypes.impl
       285 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties
       196 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.extendedProperties.impl
        23 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math
        24 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships
         2 org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.relationships.impl
      2076 org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main
      1224 org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.impl
         1 org.openxmlformats.schemas.schemaLibrary.x2006.main
      9857 org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main
      6559 org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.impl
     12120 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main
      9712 org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl
         4 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707
         4 schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE5DEF300EF120945DCDBF7C4471C059C
      1170 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel
      1223 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.impl
       285 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice
       124 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeOffice.impl
         2 schemasMicrosoftComOfficePowerpoint
         3 schemasMicrosoftComOfficeWord
      2858 schemasMicrosoftComVml
      2529 schemasMicrosoftComVml.impl
```

Comment: Did you try `You may try using --multi-dex option` as mentionned in the error message ?

Comment: I've read about it but I haven't seen any simple explanation on how to implement it.

Comment: http://jayway.github.io/maven-android-plugin/dex-mojo.html#dexMultiDex and also here http://jayway.github.io/maven-android-plugin/dex-mojo.html#dex